# How to sample a signal from a continuous time domain in to a input port digital design (Simulink to HDL integration)

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, system-verilog, hdl

I am doing Simulink based Hardware software co-simulation. I have a simulink block which is outputing fixed point 32 bit data in a continuous domain. I want to send this data to an HDL design  again in fixed point 32 bit format. Whenever i integrate the two blocks together, i am getting error. I tried adding quantizer but it only works on uint/double data types which is not acceptable to the HDL block. How can I discretize the data such that it is acceptable in the RTL domain? If i add unit delay,it works but the data is delayed which is not fair

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I have voted to close this question, because I don't think it gives enough information to understand what is being asked. (I have worked on and project managed IC designs with hundreds of thousands of gates of DSP doing digital demodulation, so if I can't understand what you're asking...) Please could you flesh it out?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what tools are you using and how are you interfacing them ?

Answer (score 0):

To sample a continuous signal and convert it to digital electronics, you usually need an ADC: "Analog to digital converter".
You should start by googling ADC integration.